# LoadingRoute only called once for dynamic segments

Tags: ember.js

How does one get ember to call the LoadingRoute each time one a dynamic route e.g. product/1 and product/2.

I've create a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/supiduti/4/) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Ember is assuming that you've loaded the collection of zoobats from within the zoo route. In a real app, you obviously wouldn't put timeouts in there, so each item on the zoobat route would render instantly and wouldn't need a loadingroute.

Comment: That doesn't feel like a good assumption as it means one has to return the entire product or client or whatever table which seems wrong.  Given that what you have said seems to be embers behavior, How does one manually override this behavior and force ember to show the LoadingRoute for each dynamic segment?

Comment: You can specify the loading state on a per route basis by using the action hooks described in this article. There is a blurb about the legacy LoadingRoute at the bottom, too: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around that sly7-7 posted which works can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/supiduti/9/)

Basically define a LoadingRoute at most one level down from the route with the dynamic segment. For

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo');
  this.resource('zoo', function(){
    this.route('bat', {path: "/:bat_id"});
  });
});
```

this means having a ZooLoadingRoute in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to eager load all zoobats, the first time you go to any bat resource, you could change your router to

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo');
  this.resource('bat', {path: "/zoo/:bat_id"});
});
```

Now define App.BatRoute and change link-to's route from 'zoo.bar' to 'bar'. You will get loading for each dynamic route, without adding ZooLoadingRoute and you don't have to eager load all zoobats.

Check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/supiduti/13)

Comment: Thanks Subramaniam.  the reason your method works is because the way you have defined your routes it is only 1 level up from ApplicationRoute.  If it was further up your answer would not work.